# Vector Geoprocesing Intersection not working in QGIS 3.0?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, intersection, qgis-3

I have not been able to create an intersection layer in QGIS 3.0. The method has been working fine in QGIS 2.18. The method I have been using is to select Vector >> Geoprocessing tools >> Intersection. I then choose the Input layer and
Intersect layer from the dropdown menu, and click on Run. In QGIS 2.18 it works fine. In QGIS 3.0 I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\Intersection.py",
>   line 135, in processAlgorithm indexB =
>   QgsSpatialIndex(sourceB.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setSubsetOfAttributes([]).setDestinationCrs(sourceA.sourceCrs(),
>   context.transformContext())), feedback) Exception: unknown. Execution
>   failed after 0.23 seconds

Is there is setting in QGIS 3.0 that I need to select?

Comment: 3.0 is still young, so this is probably a bug. Report it here: https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues

Answer (score 0):

Intersection seems to work fine with QGIS 3.0.0 (0def61c) on Ubuntu 17.04.  I also tested with layers that had different CRSs.